# A children’s show I can’t seem to remember the name of

Tags: story-identification, tv

The show, from what I remember, is about kids who fight bad guys who are these grey guys in black suits. One of the fight scenes is in a warehouse and outside the warehouse there are these wooden shipping boxes they hide behind.

I remember a white girl and a black boy and I’m not sure about the rest. The girl kind of reminds me of Alexa Vega.

They go on these missions regularly by putting on glasses that resemble virtual reality gaming goggles. In between missions they meet in a sort of limbo which is just this white ‘realm’.

One of the scenes I remember is of the girl fighting in a Spartan inspired arena and ‘king’ or ‘sultan’ of sorts is giving thumbs up or thumbs down for the fighting.

I think the final scene of the show is a victory after this fight in the arena and then they go home.

I used to watch this when I was 8-11 (2009-2012) years old but it was in a pirated dvd so I’m not even sure. But the show was definitely late 1990s to early 2000s.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Live action? Puppets? Traditional animation? CGI?

Comment: If it is a correct answer, you can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cyberkidz TV Series - In the Power of the Glove!

> Cyberkidz sci-fi TV series from 1996 featuring Zorak, the
> thousand-year-old evil wizard; Zeist, his henchman; and Kyle, Ian,
> Danica and Zak (K.I.D.Z. - get it?), who use the Power of the Glove to
> protect Cyberland and Earth.

They use 3D glasses and power gloves to meet in white void, there is a black kid and a white girl and two others. The glasses and the gloves are the source of their powers.
(as seen here at 3:10 mark:

)

See if this rings any bells:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLO6yAAJAjdSLEArkcJFsEnMvKMAPClx3g

Screenshot from once an episode occurrence (because they meet in the void at least once):
[image: Screenshot from the show]

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH!